# How can you debug a process using gdb without pausing it?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a process that is already running, and I want to debug it with GDB. I've been using

```
gdb --pid $PID
```

However, when I do this, the process pauses. I'd like to attach to the process without pausing it, and look around in its memory while it's still running. Is this possible? Alternatively, is there a way to "fork" the process so that I can look at its memory, without stopping/pausing the process?

Comment: You can use the `gcore` command to grab a snapshot of the process's memory, then use gdb to look at that. Depending on your operating system, this may or may not require suspending the process briefly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way in gdb to attach without some sort of pause.

The Linux kernel provides some support for this via `PTRACE_SEIZE`, but gdb doesn't use this yet.  There's a [bug in bugzilla you can track, *"Bug 15250 - use `PTRACE_SEIZE` and `PTRACE_INTERRUPT`"*](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15250)

Meanwhile you could try setting gdb into "observer mode".  Then you could attach and use `continue &` to continue the process in the background.  You may need to set various settings, like `target-async`, depending on the gdb version.

I am not totally certain if this will work.  It is worth a try.  Note that there is a window in which the program will be paused.  This is unavoidable right now.

Comment: I'm going to assume the bug on bugzilla is https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15250 and add it as a link, please update if I'm wrong.