# Live monitoring variables of compiled (c) code

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm running a headless aarch64 based embedded linux system. on this system there is a main program running which is a compiled bit o C code. However I would like to be able to monitor this program while it continues doing its thing.

During my education I worked with the XCP-protocol to monitor systems and adjust them on the fly. But that is hands on, I would like to automate it with python or javascript so I can handle the data for other purposes.

So in short, there's a compiled bit of C-code running on a Linux system and I want to be able to see the value of its variables with something like javascript or python.

I did some testing with GDB but that seems to pause the execution of the program which can't happen, maybe only for a quick bit when its starting but not after.

I've found this previous post:
[How can you debug a process using gdb without pausing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508017/how-can-you-debug-a-process-using-gdb-without-pausing-it?rq=1)

However when i type continue after setting all of the related settings that I could find, it doesnt let me look up the value of a variable anymore using a command like p .

Comment: Do you have access to the sources, can you modify them or it needs to be an external program?

Comment: yes i can modify the sources, but they tend to be automatically generated from a simulink model, so it may not be preferable if it can't be automated.

Comment: Is there some option of logging?

Comment: the current method that was tried was writing the values of some variables to files in shared RAM, but this was causing a lot of drag on the system. So i guess that kind of fits it. But some form of logging is available yes.

Comment: Without memory monitoring logging is pretty much the best you can get, considering you're debugging (process that is supposed to be in test phase) it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Maybe try Data Logging from Generated Code: https://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/logging.html#bp6h8aq-11

Comment: @BillMorgan I'm not sure if that works this way for me, I use a custom blockset, then generate C code from it, which then compiles to a .elf file that runs on the system.
It's not a simulation that is being run, it's an embedded controller that's running a physical system. So it could be running for years on end, so logging all of the data might not be the best solution. i just wan't a list of the current state of the system.